# Symfony2: DataMapper

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, datamapper

I have read many about some DataMapper pattern.

A DataMapper should as long as I have understood map a Form Model Object to the Entity Object. So is in use as some sort of Adapter.

Did I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

No, [Data Mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) is about mapping objects to the database — it has nothing to do with forms in any way.

The main advantage of the Data Mapper pattern is that you can evolve both your object model and the database schema independently — without bending one to another. In contrast, with [Active Record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) you have to bend one of them — usually good database design is sacrificed to please the object model.

Doctrine 1.x was an implementation of something between Active Record and Data Mapper; Doctrine 2.x is a pure Data Mapper implementation.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer! But doesn't the DataMapper of Doctrine still bend good database design? I mean keeping a DB in NF3 to NF5 and still working with Doctrine is possible but has a wide distance to good

Comment: When talking about bending, I didn't mean it in a good way. What I meant is that, say, with Doctrine 1.x you sometimes had to adapt your database to Doctrine ­— by denormalizing it or messing it up in some other way.

Answer (score 2):

elnur is right about DataMapper, if you want to know about mapping forms to objects, you can use what symfony calls a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).

Comment: Symfony2 actually has a DataMapper. It's sadly undocumented: http://joshuaestes.me/2015/01/25/symfony2_form_data_mapper/